# sqlserverexception login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

when i am trying to connect sql server 2008 with jdbc an exception has occured as fellows
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'.

the code is shown as follows

```
import java.sql.*;

public class myjdbc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sDriverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"; 
        String Name = "sa";
        String Pswd = "1111";
        String aDBUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=pasdb";
        //String bDBUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://scu-PC\\Barney;databaseName=pasdb;integratedSecurity=true";
        try {
            Class.forName(sDriverName);
            DriverManager.getConnection(aDBUrl,Name,Pswd);
            //DriverManager.getConnection(bDBUrl);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {         
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }
}
```

When i use the bDBUrl method to connect SQL, all goes well; when i use the aDBUrl mehtod, the error goes out.

PS: i can login sql server by using account sa through sql server management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bDBUrl` the username and password are ignored, and integrated security (your windows account) is used. So your own user account is used to login (and is allowed to login).

With `aDBUrl` you use the `sa` user and now login fails. There might be several causes: SQL authentication is completely disabled, there is no user `sa`, the user `sa` is disabled, the password of `sa` is not the password you specify, or the user `sa` has no access to the specified database.

Also note that `aDBUrl` and `bDBUrl` are different and might not be pointing to the same computer, or if `scu-PC` is the same as your localhost: they might be different instances.